# Interviewing a group of users

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, ethnography, user-interviews

I am organising some interviews with existing users to validate existing and future features for a product. I had everything planned to run individual interviews, consisting of general questions and usability tests on a few prototypes.
The problem is that the customer facing person managed to organise a group session only and this is the only way I'm going to get to talk with users.

What are the best practices to make an effective group interview in order to validate some early concepts about new features and interfaces?